# I'm testing an android app for different status codes. How to I force them using the volley library

Tags: android, android-volley

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;

    try {
        Utils.checkSessionCookie(response.headers, mContext);
        Utils.checkUserId(response.headers, mContext);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }

//        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : response.headers.entrySet()) {
//            if (entry.getKey().equals("Userkey") || entry.getKey().equals("Set-Cookie")) {
//                Log.d(TAG, "Response - " + entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
//            }
//        }
    try {
        String json = new String(Utils.base64Decode(response.data),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement element = parser.parse(json);

        //Normal print
        Log.d(TAG, json);

        if(mSelection != null){
            JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(json);
            json = findElementsChildren(jsonElement, mSelection).toString();
            element = parser.parse(json);
        }

        if(element.isJsonArray()){
            JsonArray array = (JsonArray) element;
            ArrayList elements = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                elements.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i).toString(), clazz));
            }
            return (Response<T>) Response.success(elements, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } else {
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (Exception e){
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the problems you're facing? With just Code, there's nothing we can (or should) do.

Comment: I want to be able to pass in a status code and have the request return me that error

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question ist just a single sentence and a wall of code. Noone will spend time trying to understand this code.